# Showing tooltip for a checkbox inside a modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, metronic

I have a modal and inside that modal I have a checkbox which is acting like a switch button.I want to show a tooltip for that checkbox when I will hover on it.How to do this . Title is not working here.

My markup is like this.

```html
<input id="chkSyncType" title="The tooltip"  type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="&nbsp;Auto&nbsp;" data-off-text="&nbsp;Manual&nbsp;" value="false" checked="checked" />
```

Final html is

```
<div class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-on bootstrap-switch-id-chkSyncType bootstrap-switch-animate" style="width: 161.818px;"><div class="bootstrap-switch-container" style="width: 240px; margin-left: 0px;"><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-success" style="width: 80px;">&nbsp;Auto&nbsp;</span><span class="bootstrap-switch-label" style="width: 80px;">&nbsp;</span><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 80px;">&nbsp;Manual&nbsp;</span><input id="chkSyncType" title="mytooltip" type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="&nbsp;Auto&nbsp;" data-off-text="&nbsp;Manual&nbsp;" value="false" checked="checked"></div></div>
```

Comment: Title is working here. What is not working? checked edited question

Comment: it is not showing the tool tip

Comment: have edited your question, can you accept it?

Comment: title is working in chrome, I can see the tool tip. may be its not working on your browser.

Comment: When creating a code snippet, please ensure that it is functional. It seems that you only included the markup with no additional libraries (if your intention is to use a third party library for tooltip display instead of relying on the browser's `title` attribute), so we cannot actually see what is *not* working

Comment: Hi all title is not working, Just noticed final html is rendering something which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: I can still see the title on Chrome. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Its working fine in Chrome here...  https://jsfiddle.net/v6e5t1zo/  There must be something else going on at your end thats causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the title as a tooltip, you can do something like this.

```css
input {
  position: relative;
}

input::after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
  
  /* just for demo purposes :) */
  transition: all .3s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  bottom: -3rem;
}

input:hover::after{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-on bootstrap-switch-id-chkSyncType bootstrap-switch-animate" style="width: 161.818px;">
  <div class="bootstrap-switch-container" style="width: 240px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-success" style="width: 80px;">&nbsp;Auto&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="bootstrap-switch-label" style="width: 80px;">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 80px;">&nbsp;Manual&nbsp;</span>
    <input id="chkSyncType" title="mytooltip" type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="&nbsp;Auto&nbsp;" data-off-text="&nbsp;Manual&nbsp;" value="false" checked="checked">
  </div>
</div>
```