# Styling a tooltip appearing in span

Tags: jquery, css

I have a span with title attribute for showing tooltip. It is showing a default tooltip. But I want the tooltip to be shown as a tooltip with black background color a and white text color.
How I can do that?

My span HTML looks like this

```
<span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-success" 
      title="my span tooltip" style="width: 42px;">ON</span>
```

Thanks and Regards

Comment: can you update some code to fiddle

Comment: can you share working code/snnipet?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996621/showing-tooltip-for-a-checkbox-inside-a-modal/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the title text in your CSS to create a new tooltip element. You don't have to add a new el. Just use a pseudo-selector like such:

```
span:hover:after{
content: attr(data-title);
display:block;
//more width, height, background etc. here
}
```

Then use `data-title` instead of title to avoid the double-tooltip.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nyybsu1o/2/

Comment: Updating now - I see what you meant.

Comment: I am seeing your tooltip fiddle and this is showing me tooltip 2 times. One from the hover event written in css and one from the default behaviour.

Comment: I just updatd my answer and fiddle to use data-title to avoid the original behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this already done here, sharing it with you. It uses quite the technique as answered by itamar, but is little more fancier with added cosmetics. You may improve it further according to your need.

Here it is:

```css
.tooltip {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip:after {
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  padding: .5em;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus autem ipsum, culpa cum cumque perferendis, non, nisi a sint debitis eaque sit? Ratione vel aliquid eos, accusamus alias id perferendis.</p>
<p>Iusto ipsum laudantium sint, soluta necessitatibus alias, aperiam, iste nisi <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Illum possimus voluptas aperiam">consequuntur odit</span> culpa minima deserunt ipsa corrupti pariatur tempore enim expedita dignissimos maiores
  tenetur non dicta unde autem velit vitae.</p>
<p>Consectetur placeat veniam <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Cupiditate officia adipisci necessitatibus consectetur voluptates, tempore, aspernatur.">nobis excepturi</span> minus explicabo accusantium, nulla. Ducimus sequi quia consequuntur temporibus sapiente recusandae expedita ad voluptatum facere fugit, velit asperiores illum possimus voluptas aperiam nemo. Tenetur, ut.</p>
<p>Possimus impedit commodi amet fugiat, eligendi, nesciunt, labore natus ipsum vel nihil rem pariatur accusamus non at tenetur nobis est. Voluptas natus itaque, neque distinctio numquam animi velit, totam voluptatum.</p>
<p>Cumque temporibus blanditiis <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Voluptates provident non distinctio porro sit asperiores minus, quia molestias, animi sapiente suscipit maiores labore? Ipsa excepturi, possimus!">et ullam nam</span> asperiores reiciendis
  odit natus, voluptates. Cupiditate officia adipisci necessitatibus iste quos pariatur corrupti, sapiente in maxime commodi? Accusantium consectetur voluptates, tempore, aspernatur quibusdam similique.</p>
```

I hope it was helpful. Cheers!

EDIT: You may also take a look at [Ballons.css](https://kazzkiq.github.io/balloon.css/) which is specifically meant for drawing tooltips using nothing else but just CSS.